# can i put a message when the dropdown list has zero data to be shown

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

i have a kendo dropdown list and its working,, im just wondering if i can put a message that will pop up or to be shown when the kendodropdown have zero data to be shown...can i do it using jquery???

heres my code

```
<input id="ddlWorker" name="Worker" class:"validate[required] inputLong" style="width: 400px;" value="@workerPosId" required  />




$("#ddlWorker").kendoDropDownList({
            dataTextField: "workerName",
            dataValueField: "workerID",
            autoBind: false,


            optionLabel: {
                workerName: "--- Please Assign A Worker ---",
                workerID: ""

            },
            // define custom template
            template:
                                      '<h5>${ data.workerName }</h5>' +
'#if(data.AvailableDay_LookID) {#<p>${ data.AvailableDay_LookID }</p>#}#' +
'#if(data.StartTime && data.EndTime) {#<p>${ data.StartTime } - ${ data.EndTime }</p>#}#',

            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: '/Client/LoadWorkerDropdownList?clientCusPosShiftId=' + clientCusPosShiftId,
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST"
                    }
                }
            }

        });
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var dropdownlist= $("#ddlWorker").kendoDropDownList({
                dataTextField: "workerName",
                dataValueField: "workerID",
                autoBind: false,


                optionLabel: {
                    workerName: "--- Please Assign A Worker ---",
                    workerID: ""

                },
                // define custom template
                template:
                                      '<h5>${ data.workerName }</h5>' +
'#if(data.AvailableDay_LookID) {#<p>${ data.AvailableDay_LookID }</p>#}#' +
'#if(data.StartTime && data.EndTime) {#<p>${ data.StartTime } - ${ data.EndTime }</p>#}#',

                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: '/Client/LoadWorkerDropdownList?clientCusPosShiftId=' + clientCusPosShiftId,
                            dataType: "json",
                            type: "POST"
                        }
                    }
                }

            }).data("kendoDropDownList");


dropdownlist.dataSource.bind("change", function(e) {
    var raw = dropdownlist.dataSource.data();
    var length = raw.length;
    if (length < 1) {
      alert("kendodropdown have zero data");
    }
});
```

Comment: open method works only when data are bind successfully..hmm.. you way use change event on bind method.. can you please check latest edited code again

Answer (score 1):

You may try this.

use var object to store json data.

```
  var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhReq.open("POST", '/Client/LoadWorkerDropdownList?clientCusPosShiftId=' + clientCusPosShiftId, false);
  xhReq.send(null);
  var jsonObj = JSON.parse(xhReq.responseText);
```

Use javascript length property to check length

```
if (jsonObj.length < 1)
    alert("kendodropdown have zero data");
```

Bind datasource

```
$("#ddlWorker").kendoDropDownList({
            dataTextField: "workerName",
            dataValueField: "workerID",
            autoBind: false,


            optionLabel: {
                workerName: "--- Please Assign A Worker ---",
                workerID: ""

            },
            // define custom template
            template:
                      '<h5>${ data.workerName }</h5>' 
                      + '#if(data.AvailableDay_LookID) {#<p>${ data.AvailableDay_LookID }</p>#}#' 
                      + '#if(data.StartTime && data.EndTime) {#<p>${ data.StartTime } - ${ data.EndTime }</p>#}#',

            dataSource: jsonObj 

        });
```

Comment: sir it has a problem.. it always says zero data even thought it have data's..and can i do it in a way that the message will be shown after you click the dropdown???

Comment: and the the dropdown is not working also when i try to add the code you give

Answer (score 0):

if your code is workable than try this

to check datasource size at once use "dataSource.one" event

call "dataSource.one" event & check dataSource size

```
 var dropdownlist = $("#ddlWorker").kendoDropDownList({
    ....
    ....
 }).data("kendoDropDownList");

 dropdownlist.dataSource.one("change", function() {

 //event handled will be called only once.
 var raw = dropdownlist.dataSource.data();
 var length = raw.length;
 if (length < 1)
     alert("kendodropdown have zero data");

 });
```

to check datasource size more than once use "open" method, check below code

```
var dropdownlist = $("#ddlWorker").kendoDropDownList({
     ....
     ....
     open: function() {
          var raw = dropdownlist.dataSource.data();
          var length = raw.length;
          if (length < 1)
              alert("kendodropdown have zero data");

         }
}).data("kendoDropDownList");
```

Comment: sir its working.. just a little more its just show the message for just once... how can i make it that to the point the the message will appear every time i click the dropdown.. thanks

Comment: for that, you need to use event "open".

Comment: sorry open is not an event its an method of kendoDropDownList, you need to specify at the time of kendoDropList creation.. have a look at latest edited version..

Comment: sir is the edited version is missing some opening and closing brackets??? or that is intended that way... im having an error on closing brackets.. showing error like this

Comment: "uncaught syntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Comment: you may be missing .data("kendoDropDownList"); at the end